# How to add 0.0.0.0 in hosts file before every domain in gedit?

Tags: 12.04, gedit, hosts, etc

When I add 0.0.0.0 i do it manually and it takes long time, how to apply in one step.

for example i want block admedia.com and subdomains , i open terminal and type sudo gedit /etc/hosts, and put domain and subdomain and add 0.0.0.0 before each domain. the question is how to add 0.0.0.0 in one step.

note:- i'am not expert user so explanation wish be simple and easy steps.

Comment: Can you please elaborate?  You have 1 host file where you need to add 0.0.0.0 host.domain.tld, a lot of times over?  Or you have a bunch of host files where every time you add a domain you have to do it to each one?

Comment: i  have a bunch of host files where every time i add a domain  have to do it to each one

Comment: domain and subdomain.

Comment: If you're working with multiple host machines, where you're adding an entry into each host file of each host machine, there isn't a simple, easy, solution.   A DNS server would seem to fit this most appropriately.  One dns server, where the 10 hosts, etc, connect to it for that information.  I don't know what you're really trying to accomplish, but it's probably outside the scope here anyway.  If you like, please update your question with more information and as to why you have so many hosts to add to begin with.

Comment: it's just simple i'am home ubuntu user and for example i want block some ads like       ads.pennyweb.com
0.0.0.0  ads.people.com.cn
0.0.0.0 ads.persgroep.net
0.0.0.0 ads.peteava.ro
0.0.0.0  ads.pg.valueclick.net

Comment: I'd suggest you update your question to fully explain what you're trying to achieve, with regards the adblocking.

Comment: I'd also fully explain how you're editing it now and under what conditions? Where are you getting the list of urls from? Are you adding them via a command line editor such as nano?

Comment: for example i want block admedia.com and subdomains , i open terminal and type sudo gedit /etc/hosts, and put domain and subdomain and add 0.0.0.0 before each domain. the question is how to add 0.0.0.0 in one step.

Comment: It would be easier if you used the command line for this, instead of gedit.

Comment: @mario is there a reason you are trying to block all these domains?  There's literally thousands of these; no easy way to 'detect' these and block them

Comment: @ThomasW. i stay hours to block like these domins ads,pop-up. my hosts file is 60108 line till now with no affect of my laptop.

Comment: @mario not my point.  are you trying to block all of these ad domains on your own computer to prevent ads on those web browsers?  Are ad blockers insufficent?

Comment: I see good results with hosts file than adblock, my priority is my connection refused between my browser and these domain, you know also ransomware spread from this ads,pop-up. http://arstechnica.com/security/2016/03/big-name-sites-hit-by-rash-of-malicious-ads-spreading-crypto-ransomware/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One small nitpick: if you're using a GUI application like gedit, always use `gksudo` instead of `sudo` to avoid `root` possibly owning some of your files, messing things up.

For example, `gksudo gedit /etc/hosts`.

---

1. Move the cursor to the line *before* the first line you want to precede with `0.0.0.0`.
2. In the `Search` menu, select `Find and Replace…`.
3. In the `Find` field, type `\n`.
4. In the `Replace with` field, type `\n0.0.0.0\t`.
5. Press the `Find` button.
6. Press the `Replace` button repeatedly until all the lines you wanted to add `0.0.0.0` to are complete.

You can speed things up with the `Replace All` button, but that will add `0.0.0.0` to the front of all lines, even if they already have `0.0.0.0`; not handle the first line of the file; and add a line at the end of the file with just `0.0.0.0` in it.